# Repaint Rectangle on Rectangle without flashing, Windows 7, Delphi

Tags: delphi, repaint, flicker, z-order

I wish to draw a graph, and paint a rectangle in the centre of it.
Using Delphi 7, it has been done like this:

```
with graphform.canvas do begin
    brush.color:=clwhite;
    brush.style:=bssolid;
    pen.color:=clwhite;
    rectangle(1,y0,639,y0-341);
end;

//short wait while other things happen

graphform.waitlab.Invalidate;
```

That causes terrible flashing: the white rectangle washes waitlab away, then after the short wait, waitlab is repainted. waitLab is the smaller rectangle in the center of the larger field.

If I turn off window painting, the window doesn't get painted at all. If I turn off window painting, then turn it on again and repaint the window, I've got the original problem: I'm painting the rectangle white, then colored.

The canvas code runs (and must run) in a paint event handler, since the white field is not a Delphi control, it needs to be explicitly repainted on every paint message to the form. waitlab is a Delphi control which Delphi repaints after the invalidate. The invalidate code line is not in the paint event handler: that would cause a tight loop.

**BUT** the code also is run asynchronously on a comm event which changes some of the other things painted on the form, and does a direct call to this painting code.

I don't know if there is a technical solution, or if there is a solution for the program logic. What do you suggest?

Comment: What is the context of this code? Is it running in response to a `WM_PAINT` event? And if not, why not?

Comment: Painting code, like the `with` block above, should execute in response to a `WM_PAINT` message, i.e., in your `OnPaint` handler. I also assume that is the case in my answer.

Comment: What happens if you remove `short wait while other things happen`?

Comment: This is confusing. White rectangle, smaller rectangle, larger field, white field, waitlab, window... I have no idea which is what and what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`InvalidateRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `Invalidate`.

Using `InvalidateRect`, you can tell Windows only to repaint a specific rectangle in your canvas. In this case, `Rect(1,y0,639,y0-341)`.

Comment: I already invalidate the small rectangle. I do that because it has been washed out by the larger rectangle(1,y0,639,y0-341).